# How do I convert a non zero padded day string to a useful date in pandas

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to import a date string with non-zero padded day, zero padded month, and year without century to create a datetime e.g. (11219 to 01/12/19).  However, pandas cannot distinguish between the day and the month (e.g. 11219 could be 11th February, 2019 or 1st December, 2019).

I've tried using 'dayfirst' and the '#' in the day e.g. %#d, but nothing works. Code below, any advise?

**Code:**

```
df_import['newDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df_import['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y', dayfirst = True)
```

**Error:**

> time data '11219' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)

Comment: The problem with this is format is whether `11119` is `1-11-19` or `11-1-19`?

Comment: `format='%d%m%Y'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since only the *day* is not zero-padded, the dates are unambiguous. They can simply be parsed by Pandas if we add the pad:

```
pd.to_datetime(df_import['Date'].str.zfill(6), format='%d%m%y')
```

Comment: That worked great, I wasn't aware of the 'zfill()' option, which is very useful for such a case. Many thanks,

Answer (score 1):

1. use zfill()
2. A custom function can also be used if you want to handle more cases.

   ```
   def getDate(str):
      return #logic to parse

   df_import['newDate'] = df_import['Date'].apply(getDate)
   ```